# Splitting a dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas, split

What I want to do is pretty simple, in other languages. I want to split a table, using a "for" loop to split a data frame every fifth row.

The idea is that I have dataframe that adds a new row, every so often, like answering a form with different questions and every answer is added to a specific column, like Google Forms with SpreadSheet.

What I have tried is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
dp=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=dp)
for i in range(0, len(dp)):
   if i%5==0:
      df = df1.iloc[i,:]
      print(df)          
print(df)
```

Which I know isn't much but nevertheless it is a try. Now, what I can't do is create a new variable with the new dataframe every time the loop reaches the `i mod 5 == 0` row.

Comment: It's not clear what output your desired output is.  Do you want lots of individual five-row dataframes stored in varables?  Or are you trying to convert a flat list into a single dataframe with rows and columns?  Maybe you're just trying to print to the screen five-rows at a time.

Comment: I understand the confusion. What I want to do is the first one. I want to generate variables that store a dataframe every fifth row. 
For example: I want rows 0 through 4 stored in a variable named V1, 5 through 9 stored in V2 etc.

Can this be done?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Jason.  See my updated answer below.  I create a list of dataframes, `dfs`.  That way dfs[0] is the first data frame, dfs[1] is the second, etc...

Answer (score 1):

#### [`numpy.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

```
lod = np.split(df1, np.arange(1, 16, 5))

print(*lod, sep='\n\n')

   0
0  0

   0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5

     0
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10  10

     0
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  15
```

---

```
lod = np.split(df1, np.arange(0, 16, 5)[1:])

print(*lod, sep='\n\n')

   0
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

   0
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
9  9

     0
10  10
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14

     0
15  15
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to convert a flat list into rows and columns using a known number of fields.

I'd do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

numFields = 3   # this is five in your case
fieldNames = ['color', 'animal', 'amphibian'] # totally optional 

# this is your 'dp'
inputData = ['brown', 'dog','false','green', 'toad','true']

flatDataArray = np.asarray(inputData)

reshapedData = flatDataArray.reshape(-1, numFields)

df = pd.DataFrame(reshapedData, columns=fieldNames) # you only need 'columns' if you want to name fields

print(df)
```

which gives:

```
    color   animal  amphibian
0   brown   dog     false
1   green   toad    true
```

--UPDATE--

From your comment above, I see that you'd like an arbitrary number of dataframes- one for each five-row group.  Why not create a list of dataframes (i.e. so you have `dfs[0]`, `dfs[1]`)?

```
# continuing with from where the previous code left off...

dfs = []

for group in reshapedData:
     dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(group))

for df in dfs:
    print(df)
```

which prints:

```
   0
0  brown
1    dog
2  false

   0
0  green
1   toad
2   true
```